# onSelectionChange(e) doesn't seem to trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

For reasons I can't fathom so far, function onSelectionChange(e) in one of my google sheets apps is no longer working. I've simplified the problem solving by reducing the function to this:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('Code ran');

}
```

The code runs in the editor when I select it, but it does not run at all when I change selections on the sheets.

I have tried the following fixes, none of which work:

1. Delete oSC(e) function and replace it.
2. Delete function, exit app, re-enter app, and replace oSC(e).
3. Delete function, exit Google, exit app, re-enter app, and replace oSC(e).

Note:
(a) In other sheets apps, my onSelectionChange(e) functions work.
(b) When I'm typing in the script editor, the autofill seems to think that I have a function called onSelectionChange(), but I don't.

I have followed up on a few posts respecting problems with `onSelectionChange()` in StackOverflow, but none seem to apply to this situation.

Comment: Show Executions tab.

Comment: On execution, the function locks up on the dialogue box. So, "Execution started ..." and that's all. Another weird thing. Although it locks up in chrome, the dialogue box executes when I'm running the function in Firefox. But I've got no pop-up blocks running in chrome.

Comment: IN debugger, Call stack is spinning and message is "Waiting for breakpoint ..." It's as if the  code thinks I have a dialogue box in front of me, but it's not there. Another point to add now ... no class UI features are working within onSelectionChange();

Comment: I always have to setup the onSelectionChange trigger and then close the container and reopen it.

Comment: What browser? What OS? Mobile or desktop?

Comment: In the end, I resolved this problem by using onSelectionChange(e) to trigger another function, onSelectionChangeAlt(e). I really don't know why it works better than onSelectionChange(e), but it does.